# What does apply function do in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have below "apply" function, what does apply function do? can you please explain for me?

```
      def apply[K,V](m1:Map[K,V], m2:Map[K,V], merge: (V,V) => V): Map[K,V] = 
           combine(m1,m2,merge)
```

Comment: Given the context of your previous question, in this case `apply` is used so you can write: `MapCombine(m1, m2, foo)` instead of `MapCombine.combine(m1, m2, foo)`

Answer (score 0):

The `apply` function in companion objects and classes has a special meaning in that if an object/class is instantiated without specifying the function, it is the one which is run.

E.g.

```
object DDF { def apply(text :String) = println(s"got $text") }

DDF("text")    // object called like function. function actually called is apply(String) here.
```

In your example, the apply function merely calls combine. so `X(a,b,c)` is the same as `X.combine(a,b,c)`.

The technique is how we have achieve multiple constructors on classes too.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, you can have primary and secondary constructors without `apply` methods. Overloading constructors is a feature even in Java, and Scala allows it as well. It's often cleaner to have a factory in a companion object, but that's a matter of style, not a requirement. Scala 3 makes it even easier, by having constructors synthesize `apply` methods in most cases.